# Change the icon for incoming notification in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.6

Good day guys, How to change the icon if there's a new incoming notification in Laravel?

I already installed Laravel Notification `Database Notification` and make a notification table `php artisan notifications:table` and migrate it. When I tested the code it will notify the user but to be able to change the icon you need to refresh the page first.

Is there way to automatically change the icon without refreshing the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Notification (Database Notification) Icon doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754021/laravel-notification-database-notification-icon-doesnt-change)

Comment: noted on that.. already been solved the problem.. thanks for the reply.